# Is it possible to run a Makefile from Java?

Tags: java, makefile

I was searching the Internet but only got examples of generating a Java Makefile. My case is different, what if I have a Makefile, but I just want to run it from Java?

Answer (score 2):

You don't really "run" a makefile, rather, you run the `make` utility and it looks for a file called "makefile" or "Makefile" in your current directory and processes the commands in that file.  So you need to execute `make` from within your java app.  You can do this via `Runtime.exec()`.  For more information see http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29 and http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=1

One potential issue you should look out for is that `make` may or may not exist on the machine that your program runs on, and even if it does exist, it may be located in a non-standard location. On my machine, it's `/usr/bin/make`, but it could be located elsewhere.  Be careful to account for this.

Comment: And another issue is that makefiles tend to be non-portable.

Comment: oh thanks, sorry for not replying for a long time. @echo thanks for the advice, i just ran the make utility for the makefile, not from java. thanks for replies!

Comment: Doesn't using Runtime.exec() entail a lot of performance overhead? I realize that, at times, there may be no alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use Runtime.exec to run the make application. However, as someone previously stated, you should account for conditions when the file may not be present or present in another location. I suggest you to have a look at java.io.File javadoc which provides this functionality. Also, don't forget to capture the error stream for logging/debugging purposes. Many a times, programmers only implement the input and output streams.